# cakephp HABTM and dependency upon another foreign model

Tags: has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.4

I have a Resource HABTM Room. The Room model depends on another model Building. How can i integrate this dependency?

```
class Resource extends AppModel {

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Room' =>
        array(
            'conditions' => array('Room.building_id = Building.id'),
        )
    );
}

class Room extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array('Building');

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Resource');

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'name' => 'CONCAT(Building.short, Room.floor, ".", Room.number)'
    );
```

In another model and belongsTo linking i did it this way:

```
public function beforeFind($query) {
        parent::beforeFind($query);

        $this->bindModel(array(
            'belongsTo' => array(
                'Room' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Booking.room_id = Room.id')
                ),
                'Building' => array(
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array('Room.building_id = Building.id')
                )
            )
        ));
    }
```

But i have no clue how to bind/add the Building model to the Ressource model. What i have to add to the Resource **model** to get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you to define all relation normally and fetch data with `Containable Behavior`. Tell me what data you wants.

Comment: i didn't read much about Containable. i don't filter any fields, performance is not important.
thought there is a easy way to

Comment: Well, then tell me what your planning to... I will guide you...Update your question with what you want..

Comment: ahh, i got the point. i don't have to define the $hasAndBelongsToMany in the Resource model, when i don't need the data.

Comment: Read the documentation and read again.. and practice...